# how to extract element name and documentation from xsd using mxslt and put data into HTML table?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xsd

I have a big problem and i'm not even sure if solution exists for my problem...
So the problem is: 
I have a **xsd** file, and I need to create **XSLT** which will create html table 
with 2 columns: the first column is  for all elements names (4 example xs:element name="xxxxx") from my xsd file, and the second column is the value of that the same element name="xxxxx" but the value must be extract from xml file.

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:igt="http://www.yxz.com/global" xmlns:bgt="http://www.yxz.com/Prc" xmlns:xdb="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb" targetNamespace="http://www.yxz.com/Prc" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.yxz.com/global" schemaLocation="global.xsd"/>
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>Prc 1.0, 19.11.2010</xs:appinfo>
        <xs:documentation>Some description</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType name="TypePerson">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Person</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="zzzzz" type="igt:String35Type" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>documentation for zzzz</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="wwwww" type="igt:String35Type" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>documentation for wwwww</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

(**XML**)

```
<ns2:globalResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.yxz.com/PrcWs" xmlns="http://www.yxz.com/global" xmlns:ns3="http://www.yxz.com/Prc">  
    <ns2:Header>
        <JobId>HfC8PH1LzUIzougK8qwFm5lX5KgTVzgs</JobId>
        <MsgId>o9xVVPnVeBOZawdEqT8zOXx1g7U9tbBM</MsgId>
        <Operation Id="IO001">text</Operation>
        <Status Id="OK"/>
        <SysDate>2011-03-24T11:27:36</SysDate>
    </ns2:Header>
    <ns2:Body>
        <ns2:ViewResponse>
            <ns3:ListPerson Size="1">
                <ns3:Person>
                    <ns3:zzzzz>value of zzz</ns3:zzzzz>
                    <ns3:wwwww>value of www</ns3:wwwww>
                </ns3:Person>
            </ns3:ListPerson>
        </ns2:ViewResponse>
    </ns2:Body>
</ns2:globalResponse>
```

And i would like the [xslt] which gives html table

```
||xsd element's documentation||value of element name in xml file||
----------------------------------------------------------------
||documentation for zzzz || value of zzz||
```

Is this even possible, and how?

Comment: Even it is imaginable, it would be nice if you post the html of the table instead of a pseudo ASCII representation.

Comment: @Marko-Iskra: Have you tried the solution I've proposed? Why not any feedback yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the schema as input parameter to the processor and load the second XML using the `document()` function in the transform.

Moreover, you need to carefully include the namespaces inside the transform to be able to select the elements you need.

You can use the following test as starting point.

---

**XSLT 2.0** tested with **Saxon 9.0.0.1J** (also working as **XSLT 1.0** on **Saxon 6.5.5**)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns2="http://www.yxz.com/PrcWs"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns="http://www.yxz.com/global"
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.yxz.com/Prc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="ns2 xs ns ns3">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="values" select="document('test_input2.xml')/ns2:globalResponse/ns2:Body/ns2:ViewResponse/ns3:ListPerson"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>element documentation</th>
                <th>element value</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:element">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/>:<xsl:value-of select="xs:annotation/xs:documentation"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="$values/ns3:Person/*[local-name()=current()/@name]"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:annotation"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on the question sample inputs, produces the following HTML table:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>element documentation</th>
      <th>element value</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>zzzzz:documentation for zzzz</td>
      <td>value of zzz</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>wwwww:documentation for wwwww</td>
      <td>value of www</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Tnx empo 4 your replay, but i have to create procedure in plsql- oracle 11 DB, and there the document() function isn't working, it gives empty string. I'm trying to find workaround but havent found nothing for plsql, do you have an idea??? :)

Comment: No, if you are not running XSLT against a compliant XSLT processor, I won't be able to help you. Sorry.

Comment: Why not installing something like Saxon on the server side and performing transformations using it, instead of PL/SQL XSLT Processor?

Comment: Moreover PL/SQL XSLT Processor follows W3C XSLT final recommendation (REC-xslt-19991116), should support document(). Fire them a bug if you can.